# How to configure MUI v5 custom font-family?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following:

```
cont theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: MetricFontFaces,
    fontFamily: 'MetricHPEXS'
  } as TypographyOptions,
  components: {
    MuiFormControl: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontFamily: 'MetricHPEXS'
        }
      }
    },
    MuiInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontFamily: 'MetricHPEXS'
        },
        formControl: {
          fontFamily: 'MetricHPEXS'
        },
        input: {
          fontFamily: 'MetricHPEXS'
        }
      }
    },
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        input: {
          fontFamily: 'MetricHPEXS'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then I try to use it like this in my storybook:

```
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {story()}
        <TextField value="sdasdasd" />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
```

The custom font-family is not applying.
[image]

How do I properly create the MUI v5 theme such that all components will accept the same custom font?

Comment: Please provide a code sandbox that reproduces your problem. The code sandbox I provided in a comment for the earlier version of your question (https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-xzyt3?file=/demo.tsx) successfully customizes the font-family via the theme.

Comment: hi @RyanCogswell I tried to create a reduced use case, but even using same packages, I am not able to reproduce it... (https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-3p8w7?file=/index.tsx) I've followed `https://mui.com/customization/typography/#self-hosted-fonts` and used `CssBaseline` I just couldn't get rid of the default `font-family`... Do you have any tips and clues on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Hard to give much advice without a reproduction. I would recommend removing things from your project till you get to something simpler that works with a customized font via the theme. It should then be possible to isolate which piece of your environment is causing the problem.

Comment: Having the same issue after upgrading to v5, did you find any solution? I imported my fonts in SASS (CSS) but they are no longer applying. The only way is to add them in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, we applied the font settings directly onto the `MuiCssBaseline` in order to have everything else pick up the `font-family`. Example:

```
import { TypographyOptions } from '@mui/material/styles/createTypography';

export const muiThemeOptions = {
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'MetricHPEXS'
  } as TypographyOptions,
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: MetricFontFaces // <== here
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Where `MetricFontFaces` is a giant `string` with all of the `@font-face` defined. While this worked on applying the font globally, but because `MetricFontFaces` is a string, we couldn't apply other CSS styling easily. There is no simple way (at least I could not find them) to supply `@font-face` via the `MuiCssBaseline`.